# Selecting a value from a row where another column is max

Tags: mysql, greatest-n-per-group

I have the following SQL query:

```sql
SELECT bug.`id`,
       Max(report.`date`),
       Count(report.`id`),
       Max(version.`code`),
       bug.`id`
FROM   `bug`
       LEFT OUTER JOIN `stacktrace`
                    ON ( stacktrace.`bug_id` = bug.`id` )
       CROSS JOIN `version`
                  LEFT OUTER JOIN `report`
                               ON ( report.`stacktrace_id` = stacktrace.`id` )
WHERE  stacktrace.`version_id` = version.`id`
GROUP  BY bug.`id`
ORDER  BY Max(report.`date`) DESC;
```

I now want to select `version.name` instead of `version.code` from the row where `version.code` is maximal. Is this possible? If so, how do I do this with minimal amount of queries/overhead?

---

Relevant Tables (stripped):

```
CREATE TABLE `bug` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);

INSERT INTO `bug` VALUES();
INSERT INTO `bug` VALUES();

CREATE TABLE `version` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `code` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);

CREATE TABLE `stacktrace` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `bug_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `version_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `FK_s_v` (`version_id`),
  KEY `FK_s_b` (`bug_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_s_b` FOREIGN KEY (`bug_id`) REFERENCES `bug` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `FK_s_v` FOREIGN KEY (`version_id`) REFERENCES `version` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE
);

CREATE TABLE `report` (
  `id` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `date` datetime NOT NULL,
  `stacktrace_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `FK_r_s` (`stacktrace_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_r_s` FOREIGN KEY (`stacktrace_id`) REFERENCES `stacktrace` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

[As SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7074e1/1)

Answer (score 0):

In your case you can simply exchange the column names, **but remember** that text sorts differently then integer 1.10 comes **before** 1.2, so if you get such numbers you have to check and change your approach. see https://lists.mysql.com/mysql/183349

```
SELECT bug.`id`,
       Max(report.`date`),
       Count(report.`id`),
       Max(version.`name`),
       bug.`id`
FROM   `bug`
       LEFT OUTER JOIN `stacktrace`
                    ON ( stacktrace.`bug_id` = bug.`id` )
       CROSS JOIN `version`
                  LEFT OUTER JOIN `report`
                               ON ( report.`stacktrace_id` = stacktrace.`id` )
WHERE  stacktrace.`version_id` = version.`id`
GROUP  BY bug.`id`
ORDER  BY Max(report.`date`) DESC;
```

Comment: My fiddle example didn't represent this accurately, but version.name is not guaranteed to follow any kind of schema, so text sorting is out of question for me. I've updated the fiddle link to give a better example.

Comment: that will not wirk, you need some kind of order to determine which value to take or an GROUP'_CONCAT., basically i told you already, that you need some alhorothm that decides take this but not the 10 others. for example 1.1.0 woulb be tter displayed as three columns if integer to sort them perfectly

Comment: I have an order, it is `version.code`. I just want to get `version.name` from that row instead.